# How can I make VS Code only show editor hovers when pressing Control/Option/Cmd?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, normally when users hover a variable/function, it will show the description. It's convenient but pretty annoying because the popup also covers the above lines that I can't click to select these lines.

I disable `editor.hover.sticky` but sometimes the description is too long and I need to scroll, or the description contains links...

Is there any way to make the description shown and sticky only when I combine `Control/Option/Cmd + hover` (instead of `hover`)?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, there are no settings to get the exact behaviour you are describing.

Note that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd>+hover is already used in some language-support extensions to show extended versions of hover information.

There was a feature-request issue ticket brought up in the VS Code GitHub repo before that included a request for such functionality: [typescript hover: option to enable/disable and set modifier key
#142172](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/142172). That ticket was closed (I'm not sure why), but [one of the maintainers (mjbvz) did suggest a workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/142172#issuecomment-1031745316):

> Try setting `"editor.hover.enabled": false` to disable hovers
>
> You can then trigger hovers again using a keybinding for `editor.action.showHover`